# Timbre.JS alternative that works on mobile devices via phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Timbre.js looks like a great library for generating sound effects for mobile apps, however, it seems that there is very significant delay when trying to play a sound in the browser. The samples that work in the documentation also exhibit a delay. It even happens in the Chrome mobile emulator on Windows (on Mac, there is no delay). The docs say that "Android support is only Firefox app." I'm not quite sure what that means. In a phonegap application, the sound is not played at all

This is the code I am using with Timbre:

```
  function playSound() {            
        var sine1 = T("sin", {freq:440.00, mul:0.5});

        T("perc", {r:500}, sine1).on("ended", function() {
          this.pause();
        }).bang().play();
    }
```

If Timbre.js doesn't work on mobile, is there another means to generate simple sounds via a phonegap application?

Comment: "Android support is only Firefox app" means, it only works on firefox browser. On cordova android 4.0 they will include plugable webviews, one of them is geckoview (the firefox webview), so if you wait you might be able to use it.